# how to display mysql latest entries from each category

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

we re using CodeIgniter, we want to get 6 categories latest 10 entries by (published_date), then we will display different categories results in view. here we are using 6 colourful boxes to display 10 latest entries from each category. our SQL tables are look like this ...

**-> ci_categories**

```
cat_id | cat_name | cate_slug  | cate_title
```

**-> ci_pages**

```
page_id  | cat_id | page_title  | published_date
--------------------------------------
1    | 1       | Ttl 1       | 2014-02-22 10:22:20
2    | 2       | Ttl 2       | 2014-02-24 11:42:30
3    | 1       | Ttl 3       | 2014-02-26 10:37:21
4    | 3       | Ttl 3       | 2014-02-28 12:40:30
```

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13163031/1741542

Answer (score 0):

try this query..

`select category.*,pages.* from ci_categories category join ci_pages pages on (category.cat_id = pages.cat_id) group by pages.cat_id order_by pages.published_date DESC limit 0,10`

Comment: can we get limited 10 records from each category? and we can use left join?

Comment: i need order by latest date, and in view section in each box what code i can use to get 10 records from each category?

Comment: yeah it works, but in foreach loop, we can get 1 records from each category

Comment: we have total 6 category, this query return  6 results from pages table, 1 result from each category.

Comment: in my case, we need 10 result from 1 category, total 60 results come from pages table.

Comment: ok than I will suggest you to fetch all the categories from your `category table` and in the loop put this query..

`select category.*,pages.* from ci_categories category join ci_pages pages on (category.cat_id = pages.cat_id) where pages.cat_id = $category_id order_by pages.published_date DESC limit 0,10`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `ci_pages`.`cat_id` AS CAT_ID,
(SELECT `cat_name` FROM `ci_categories` WHERE `ci_categories`.`cat_id` = `ci_pages`.`cat_id`) AS CAT_NAME, 
(SELECT `cat_slug` FROM `ci_categories` WHERE `ci_categories`.`cat_id` = `ci_pages`.`cat_id`) AS CAT_SLUG, 
(SELECT `cat_title` FROM `ci_categories` WHERE `ci_categories`.`cat_id` = `ci_pages`.`cat_id`) AS CAT_TITLE
FROM `ci_pages` 
ORDER BY `ci_pages`.`published_date` DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

This will return the 10 last inserted values into "ci_pages" Table getting each Category's details from "ci_pages" table. Check now...

Comment: how to get each category 10 records in php loop?